# compare string and assign values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

df1

| Parc(east) | fontaine(dlf) | . | Mont Bazrougais 05 | Monrochet 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 35 | . | . | 85 |
| 29 | 50 | . | . | 50 |
| . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . |
| 10 | 20 | . | . | 35 |

df2

| names | id |
| --- | --- |
| Parc(east) | LED |
| fontanus (dlf) | MON |
| Monrochet 1 | M1 |
| Monrochet 3 | M2 |
| Monrochet 2 | LVER |
| Mont Bazrougais 05 | BR |
| Mont de est | MTE |

I want to write a code that iterate over `df2` **names**, compare the fisrt n characters of each string of df2 **names** and each string column name of `df1`. If there is a match, change the matching column name of `df1` with the corresponding value of `df2` **id**. The final df should look like `df3`.

df3

| LED |  | . | BR | LVER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Parc(east) | fontaine(dlf) | . | Mont Bazrougais 05 | Monrochet 2 |
| 24 | 35 | . | 00 | 85 |
| 29 | 50 | . | 09 | 50 |
| . | . | . | 88 | . |
| . | . | . | 100 | . |
| 10 | 20 | . | 200 | 35 |

Comment: Do you really want to add the old headers as values? That would ruin all ability to perform numerical operations.

Comment: I want to keep that row. I can remove it later to perform calculations.

Comment: OK, I added it then (but I still think it's not a good idea) ;)

Comment: n some cases there will be no match. Is it possible to do it in a more intelligent way? This data frames was built just for this purpuse. In reality the df1 header and d2 names contain long strings with different characters like parentheses. thanks

Comment: My aim is not to merge df1 and df2. df3 should keep the same number of columns as df1. My aim is to compare let say the 5 first strings of df2 names with df1 column label. and assign new column header to df1 only where there is a match. where there is no match , the new header should remain empty.

Comment: I have upadeted the dfs examples if it can help. Thanks

Comment: Your described update is almost the same as the provided answer. If you want to limit to the n first characters, you can first subset those: `df['col'].str[:n]`

Comment: where exatly. could you please rewrite  the code with the above modification

Comment: Check the update (I couldn't test it)

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df3 = df1.rename(columns=df2.set_index('names')['id'])
```

output:

```
   LED  MAN  LVER
0   24   35    85
1   29   50    50
```

If you really want the weird "header-as-data" format:

```
df3 = (pd
   .concat([df1.columns.to_frame().T, df1])
   .rename(columns=df2.set_index('names')['id'])
)
```

output:

```
     LED         MAN       LVER
0  Leeds  Manchester  Liverpool
0     24          35         85
1     29          50         50
```

##### use first n characters only;

```
n = 3

s = (df2.assign(names=df2['names'].str[:n])
    .drop_duplicates('names')
    .set_index('names')['id']
)

df3 = (pd
   .concat([df1.columns.to_frame().T, df1])
   .rename(columns=lambda x: s.loc[x[:n]])

)
```

Comment: In some cases there will be no match. Is it possible to do it in a more intelligent way? This data frames was built just for this purpuse. In reality the df1 header and d2 names contain long strings with different characters like parentheses. thanks

Comment: @hermann everything is possible, with more or less success… can you provide an updated example?